# How to get access to m_hwnd from CTaskDialog

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, taskdialog

I derive a class from `CTaskDialog` to implement an `AutoCloseButton`.

```
 HRESULT CMyTaskDialog::OnTimer(_In_ long lTime)
 {
    if (GetTickCount() - m_dwStart > (DWORD)m_nTimeout)
    {
        SendMessage(m_hWnd, TDM_CLICK_BUTTON, IDOK, 0);
    }
    
    return CTaskDialog::OnTimer(lTime);
}
```

Unfortunately `m_hWnd` is a private member in `CTaskDialog`, so I have no accces to it.

The `CTaskDialog` has the member

```
friend HRESULT CALLBACK TaskDialogCallback(_In_ HWND hwnd, _In_ UINT uNotification, _In_ WPARAM wParam, _In_ LPARAM lParam, _In_ LONG_PTR dwRefData);
```

But it is not possible to derive it (LNK2005 error (already defined in `afxtaskdialog.obj`) or I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I think you just use `ClickCommandControl(IDOK)` instead of `SendMessage(m_hWnd, TDM_CLICK_BUTTON, IDOK, 0);`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thks, this works!